# Effects of Git Push

Tags: git, git-push

Does git push completely replace the target branch in the remote repo?  All of the solutions I've seen for undoing a git push involve changing your branch locally and then redoing your git push.  Can you not undo a git push in the same way that you would undo a merge?

Comment: "Can you not undo a git push in the same way that you would undo a merge?" But how would ***you*** undo a merge? There's ***more than one way to do so*** in Git. For both undoing a push and a merge, you can either hard reset to a previous commit, or you can revert the newest commit/merge (it's a reverse patch). If you want to propagate the change to your remote repo, you would need to force push in the case of hard reset (it's a Git safety feature, to prevent losing work, among other possible bad things), or just simply do a regular push in the case of a revert.

Comment: @Cupcake I agree with you as to how I would undo a merge.  But what if someone pushes a completely foreign master branch (such as a master branch from a different repo) to your master branch?  If the entire branch is replaced, then how do you go back (because your commit history would be replaced)?

Comment: As long as you don't run `git gc` (garbage collection) in your local repo, you'll still have the commit that represents your old `master` branch sitting around in your repo for at least 2 weeks. You can find it using `git reflog`. You can then simply attach a branch to the dangling commit, and then re-push it to wherever you want. See [Data Recovery section of the free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery).

Answer (score 2):

The sub-question *"Does git push completely replace the target branch in the remote repo?"* is problematic.  Answering it with either "yes" or "no" is misleading at best.  (Compare with the old lawyer-joke question, "have you stopped beating your wife": if you say "yes" it implies you used to beat her, and if you say "no" it implies you still do!  [As a computer programmer / logician, I'd say the correct answer *can* be "no" *without* that implication, but people don't always think like that.])

Roughly, what `git push` does is the same thing that `git fetch` does, but in the opposite direction.  Over a smart protocol (like ssh), there's a whole negotiation sequence, in which "your end" and "their end" exchange information about which object(s) they have, and which ones they don't have but want.  In the case of a `push`, you tell the other end: "I have a branch label, *B*, that refers to ultimate commit C9, can I shove that on you?"  He may say "well hang on what's C9's parents" and you say "C8" and he says "I don't have that either, what's C8's parents" and you say "a merge of C6 and C7" and he says "oh I got both of those OK gimme C8 and C9".  So your end then makes a "pack" (specifically a "thin pack"—the details are not that important, but that's what the messages you see, "counting objects" and "compressing objects" and so on, are about) holding those commits and the trees and files they reference.

Once your send sends their end the objects, their end will move the pushed-branch labels to the new branch tips.  If the new branch tip labels a branch that shares no common history at all with whatever was on the remote [see **note** below], then—in effect—the answer would be "yes, it completely replaces the target branch".  That is, it sends a pack of all-new commit objects, and branch label *B* goes on the new (different) commit-tree.

More often, though, your end has a branch tip label like that on commit C9 in the description above, so you just hand over a couple of new commits (C8 and C9), and on their end, they move their branch label from C7 to C9.  In this case, the answer is "no, it does not replace the target branch, it merely augments it and moves the label forward."

There's an even more complicated, but actually quite typical, scenario though.  Perhaps "their end" has, after commit C7, a commit C10 that you *don't* have.  Meanwhile you have commits C8 and C9 you want to send.  This is a "non-fast-forward" operation.  Often a `--bare` repo is set up to reject such a push: they'll see that you're asking to add your C8 and C9, then move the branch label from C10 to C9.  That will leave one "orphaned" commit (C10), i.e., a commit with no label.  If you `--force` the push (and are allowed to), git will go ahead and do that anyway.  [Here's the **note** from earlier: pushing an unrelated branch also requires `--force`, for pretty much the same reason: git detects that some commit(s) will become unreferenced, and makes you say "I really mean to do that".]

As with All Things Git, the previous commit(s) are "still in there", they are just no longer referenced.  Of course, pushes almost always go to a `--bare` repo.  Things get a little trickier with the `--bare` repo as there is no `.git/logs` directory full of reflogs, so it's much harder now to go find a lost commit like C10, or an entire lost chain of commits.  (You, or "they" in this discussion, would need`git fsck --unreachable` to find the unreachable commit objects to recover them.)

Now, if you've done a push you should not have—let's say you meant to push commit C8, but not C9—then it *is* possible to convince the remote to change his version of the label.  Let's say you have updated `master`, and `remote.origin.url` is something like `ssh://barehost/dir/with/repo.git`.  Assume you can `ssh barehost` to log in on the host with the `--bare` repo:

```
edithost$ ssh barehost
barehost$ cd /dir/with/repo.git
barehost$ git log --oneline --decorate -2 master
5e01371 (HEAD, master) commit-C9's one line description
309b36c commit-C8's one line desc.
barehost$
```

Now you can re-label `master` to point to commit C8:

```
barehost$ git branch -f master master^
```

and poof, the `--bare` `repo.git` copy now has a branch that ends at commit C8.

You get the same effect if you just create your own branch on `edithost` and force-push it, though:

```
edithost$ git branch rewinder master^
edithost$ git push -f origin rewinder:master
```

This second `git push` will connect to `barehost` and the exchange goes something like this:

```
edithost (to barehost): branch label for you, master should go to 309b36c
barehost (to edithost): I got 309b36c but are you sure? force push?
edithost: yep, he's sure...
barehost: OK, I set master to 309b36c!
```

(actually the force flag is right in the initial exchange, but it's more fun/memorable to imagine it like this, I think).  This is really quick; there is no need for a "thin pack" of objects.

The flaw with doing either of these—`ssh`ing to `barehost` and manually resetting with `git branch`, or force-pushing a `rewinder:master` label pair—is the same: if someone else—let's call him Pat—came in and grabbed commit C9 from `barehost` in between the time you accidentally pushed it, and the time you "revoked" it, then Pat can get confused.  He's got commit C9 now, and as far as he knows, it's *supposed* to be there, right after C8.  Depending on what happens next, he may try to use it, or he might push it back over to `barehost` and make it re-appear, or whatever.

If you've made a bad commit appear somewhere shared, the "safe" (for some value of safe) thing to do to "get rid of it" is to make a new commit *after* that one, that undoes the effect of the bad one.  Everyone expects to have more new commits appear.  Unless you make advance arrangements, though, no one expects commits (or entire commit trees) to vanish.

---

### You can ignore the rest of this entirely

Here's a complete example, with some ASCII art, as requested.  I'm not sure it's much better; it might actually be worse. :-)

Let's start with a few commits on `barehost`, in a `--bare` `repo.git`.
`A0` is the initial commit, as shown below.  (This git tree just
contains one file, `somefile`, with nonsense text.)

```
barehost
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- master
```

Now I clone this to edithost:

```
$ git clone ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
$ cd repo
```

I decide I don't like any of what is in it, so I move the old
master branch out of the way and make a new one.  (Also, I don't
want `old_master` to track `origin/master` on `edithost`.)

```
$ git branch -m master old_master
$ git config --remove-section branch.old_master
```

(tracking now gone)

```
$ git checkout --orphan master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
$ git rm somefile                 # or "git rm -rf ."
rm 'somefile'
$ echo '*.o' > .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore && git commit -m C0
[master (root-commit) f09f66f] C0
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
```

Here's the resulting branch diagram.  (I leave out `HEAD` in all
cases to avoid some clutter.)

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- origin/master, old_master
C0                                 <-- master
```

I *do* want this new `master` to track the remote master
(eventually), so I'll set that up here too:

```
$ git config branch.master.remote origin
$ git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Now let's go to down and make commits `C1` through `C7`, with `C7`
being a new branch.  The contents don't really matter so I will
leave them out.  However, the picture now looks like this:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- origin/master, old_master
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6              <-- master
                     \
                       C7          <-- feep
```

Now:

```
$ git push origin feep:feep
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 2.27 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
 * [new branch]      feep -> feep
```

If I attempt to "git push origin master:master" I get an error,
of course, but I can push anyway with -f:

```
$ git push -f origin master:master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
 + dce5ffc...ae235f9 master -> master (forced update)
```

Note that this time the push said "forced update" (and "+");
that's the `-f` flag.  It also skipped `Counting objects` and just
said `Total 0`.  This is because we have *already pushed* commits
`C0` through `C7`, in the step that pushed branch "feep".  The only
thing that happened this time was removing the label "master" from
commit `A2` and sticking it on commit `C6` (not `C7`, that's only on the
"feep" branch).  But now the picture looks like this on
`edithost`:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- old_master
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6              <-- origin/master, master
                     \
                       C7          <-- origin/feep, feep
```

and like this on `barehost`:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     [no label]
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6              <-- master
                     \
                       C7          <-- feep
```

There is a key point here: **at this point, the repositories are
the same**; only the label names differ.  I can use label
`old_master` on `edithost` and turn it into a commit ID:

```
$ git rev-parse old_master
dce5ffcfcee7c5c66275189c75ea68219e8f26f5
```

and go over to `barehost` and view commits `A0`, `A1`, and `A2`.
Try this yourself, on some temporary repo (your commit IDs will
differ): `git log --oneline dce5ffcfcee7c5c66275189c75ea68219e8f26f5`

Anyway, back to `edithost`.  Let's make a new clone:

```
$ cd ..
$ git clone ssh://[redacted]/repo.git altrepo
Cloning into 'altrepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 25, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 25 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6), done.
Checking connectivity... done
$ cd altrepo
```

Running `git log --all` here shows commits `C0` through `C7`.  Let's add
a commit `C10` on top of `C6`, on the `master` branch, then push it:

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git log --oneline -1
ae235f9 C6
$ echo 'Some important documentation blah blah blah' > doc.txt
$ git add doc.txt && git commit -m C10
[master a22a608] C10
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 doc.txt
$ git push origin master:master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 368 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
   ae235f9..a22a608  master -> master
$
```

Now `barehost` has this:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     [no label]
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6 -- C10       <-- master
                     \
                       C7          <-- feep
```

Meanwhile, in `repo` (not `altrepo`) we don't have `C10` yet.
We'll be willfully blind here to illustrate "losing" a commit
if we do another forced push.

Let's go back there and merge `feep` into `master` as a non fast
forward, under commit `C8`, which we want to push back; and add
another experimental commit, which we will push "by mistake"
below:

```
$ cd ../repo
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-ff feep -m C8
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 silly.c | 19 ++++++++++++++++++-
 1 file changed, 18 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ echo experiment > experimental.file
$ git add experimental.file && git commit -m C9
```

This rather cluttered diagram shows the state of the commit trees
in `repo` on `edithost`.  Note that as far as git is concerned,
`origin/master` *has not moved yet*.  (Over in `../altrepo` git
knows about commit `C10`, but here in `./repo`, it does not.)

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- old_master
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6 _            <-- origin/master
                    \  \_ C8 -- C9 <-- master
                     \   /
                       C7          <-- origin/feep, feep
```

Let's try to push this, without -f:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git push origin master:master
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://[redacted]/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Rather than `git pull`, let's use `git fetch`, because `fetch` is
the correct opposite of `push`:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From ssh://[redacted]/repo
   ae235f9..a22a608  master     -> origin/master
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now we can see commit `C10`.  Here's the `git log` format:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 525b6fa (HEAD, master) C9
*   1933a04 C8
|\
| * c4c3302 (origin/feep, feep) C7
|/
| * a22a608 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) C10
|/
* ae235f9 C6
* e026711 C5
* f16f7cc C4
* 00d0a69 C3
* 45acc03 C2
* 07a1145 C1
* f09f66f C0
* dce5ffc (old_master) A2
* ad84d73 A1
* cee030f initial commit
```

and here's an ASCII-art version that may or may not be clearer,
but at least is in the style I have been using:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     <-- old_master

                      C10          <-- origin/master
                     /
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6 _
                    \  \_ C8 -- C9 <-- master
                     \   /
                       C7          <-- origin/feep, feep
```

I don't actually have to save the ID of commit `C10` anywhere
here because I have a copy in `../altrepo`.  Let's `push -f`:

```
$ git push -f origin master:master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 529 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
 + a22a608...525b6fa master -> master (forced update)
```

The commits are copied to the `--bare` repo, and it now has:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     [no label]

                      C10          [no label]
                     /
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6 _
                    \  \_ C8 -- C9 <-- master
                     \   /
                       C7          <-- feep
```

(If you're on barehost, it's hard to see commits `A0`, `A1`, `A2`, and
`C10`, but if you get their SHA-1 values and hand those to `git
log`, you can see that they are in fact there.)

Now let's realize: oops, mistake, did not mean to push `C9` to
`barehost`.  It's easy to rewind `barehost` from `edithost`:

```
$ git branch rewinder master^
$ git push -f origin rewinder:master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]/repo.git
 + 525b6fa...1933a04 rewinder -> master (forced update)
```

and over on `barehost`, `git log --oneline` shows that it appears
to be gone:

```
barehost$ git log --oneline --graph
*   1933a04 C8
|\
| * c4c3302 C7
|/
* ae235f9 C6
* e026711 C5
* f16f7cc C4
* 00d0a69 C3
* 45acc03 C2
* 07a1145 C1
* f09f66f C0
```

but in fact, what we have now is this:

```
A0 -- A1 -- A2                     [no label]

                      C10          [no label]
                     /
C0 -- ... -- C5 -- C6 _
                    \  \_ C8       <-- master
                     \   /  \_ C9  [no label]
                       C7          <-- feep
```

Let's use our knowledge of all the SHA-1's to "resurrect"
(label) all the missing commits and branches, on `barehost`:

```
barehost$ barehost$ git branch resurrected_master dce5ffc
barehost$ git branch recovered_c10 a22a608
barehost$ git branch recovered_c9 525b6fa
barehost$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 525b6fa (recovered_c9) C9
*   1933a04 (HEAD, master) C8
|\
| * c4c3302 (feep) C7
|/
| * a22a608 (recovered_c10) C10
|/
* ae235f9 C6
* e026711 C5
* f16f7cc C4
* 00d0a69 C3
* 45acc03 C2
* 07a1145 C1
* f09f66f C0
* dce5ffc (resurrected_master) A2
* ad84d73 A1
* cee030f initial commit
```

Now back on edithost, in `repo`:

```
$ git fetch
From ssh://[redacted]/repo
 * [new branch]      recovered_c10 -> origin/recovered_c10
 * [new branch]      recovered_c9 -> origin/recovered_c9
 * [new branch]      resurrected_master -> origin/resurrected_master
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 525b6fa (HEAD, origin/recovered_c9, master) C9
*   1933a04 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, rewinder) C8
|\
| * c4c3302 (origin/feep, feep) C7
|/
| * a22a608 (origin/recovered_c10) C10
|/
* ae235f9 C6
* e026711 C5
* f16f7cc C4
* 00d0a69 C3
* 45acc03 C2
* 07a1145 C1
* f09f66f C0
* dce5ffc (origin/resurrected_master, old_master) A2
* ad84d73 A1
* cee030f initial commit
```

They are all still there, and now they are labeled (as
origin/name) on `edithost` too.  (We should probably delete
`rewinder` on `edithost`, since we're likely done with it.)

Comment: Great answer, i enjoyed reading it! Could you enhance it with some ascii art representing the commits you are talking about? I think it would be more clear easier to read.

Comment: @Gab: That got messy... I wrote up a complete example, with some embedded diagrams, let's see how that works instead.  It's quite long and I'm not sure how much it adds.

Comment: I think the ascii art make it much more clear. And I think the second half of your answer is a bit clearer than the first half. But since the first half is more compact, I would keep both halfs. Epic answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

to undo it you have two options commit the "undo" code or replace the undo code.

To replace it you would rebase and push with the force flag on.

The commit option would show to everyone else you have changed your mind, Its safer because if people have pulled and forked, then this way they at least have a reference back to where the form came from